# POST of IFormFile not making it to action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a .NET Core application that has a controller named `Documents` with a `POST` signature like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync(CreateDocumentRequest createDocumentRequest)
```

The `CreateDocumentRequest` looks like this:

```
public class CreateDocumentRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Pretty simple. I then have a `POST` request configured in Postman like this:

- **URL:** http://localhost:9090/api/documents
- **Body:** configured as `form-data` and I have `Name`, `Description` and `File` all configured in the key-value pair interface. Furthermore, `File` is set as a `file` type so it allowed me to browse for a file.

When executing this `POST` the `DocumentsController` executes the constructor and Application Insights indicates that `PostAsync` was matched:

> Activated Event   Time    Duration    Thread
>       Application Insights: Trace "Route matched with {action = "PostAsync", controller = "Documents"}. Executing action TdlLims.MediaService.Controller.DocumentsController.PostAsync (TdlLims.MediaService)"

However, it never enters the action. My gut tells me that model binding is failing. This is for two reasons. One, all other pieces of the routing work according the Application Insights. Two, if I remove the parameters entirely, it does enter the action. What I've tried:

- Added `[FromForm]` to the `createDocumentRequest`
- Accepted only an `IFormFile` into the action, dropping the complex object
- Split up the `CreateDocumentRequest` into three different parameters
- And some other things along the way with less signifigance

Now, I'm suspect that when we're setting up Mvc, we may be missing something. We are configuring a few things, but I feel like we're missing a formatter for `multipart/form-data` somehow. I feel that way because we're using `AddMvcCore` instead of `AddMvc`:

```
.AddAuthorization()
.AddJsonFormatters()
.AddApiExplorer()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new OptionConverter());
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                });
```

Finally, I can confirm the controller is working in general, because I have a `GET` that is accessible and it makes it to the action:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(int id)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the issue was the size of the file. It would be nice if .NET Core threw an error rather than returning a `200` when something like that happened. I was trying to upload some images, and I'm going to need to figure out the right way to increase the file size, but when I uploaded a small text file the `POST` worked and the file was deserialized properly into the `IFormFile`.

I believe the attributes `RequestFormLimits` and `RequestSizeLimit` are going to play a role in setting that max file size in the end.